# How do I add the "enhance" toolbar in Adobe Illustrator CC 2014?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, cc-2014

I have adobe Illustrator CC 2014, but don't have the enhance toolbar with the features such as spot healing, clone, red eye, etc. How do I add in this toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

The features you list are part of **Photoshop** and have never been part of **Illustrator**.

Comment: do you know how I can remove things from photos? like writing off of something in the photo, or skin blemishes?

Comment: In Illustrator? You really can't. Illustrator is not meant to be used as a *photo* editing tool.

Comment: that would explain it... I thought I had seen those features in a youtube video I watched on how to delete the background...

Comment: that would explain it... I thought I had seen those features in a youtube video I watched on how to delete the background... Thank you so much for your help Scott :)